# Need to change the style of an echoed <a href=""> in php

Tags: php, css

I need to change the style of a hyperlink that is echoed in php.

This is how the line of code currently looks:

```
<div id='letter'>
  </br>A</div>
    </br>

    <?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From Artist WHERE ArtistNamn LIKE 'a%'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div id='artistlista'>";
        echo "<ul><li><a href='getArtistSongs.php?artistid=" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['ArtistNamn'] .  "</a></li></ul>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    ?>


    <div id='letter'>
  </br>B</div>
```

Code itself works as intended and extracts from the database correctly however the problem is, the link which is echoed shows up as a regular hyperlink and ignores my css id artistlista.

This is how it looks in the css file:

```
#artistlista {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}

#artistlista ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}
#artistlista ul li a:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
```

Now, as you may see from the code I have another div with the ID letter.
What I find very strange is if i simply change the id in the php code to id "letter" it does not ignore it and actually formats it correctly.

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From Artist WHERE ArtistNamn LIKE 'a%'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div id='letter'>";
        echo "<ul><li><a href='getArtistSongs.php?artistid=" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['ArtistNamn'] .  "</a></li></ul>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    ?>
```

And this is what it looks like in the css

```
#letter {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}
```

I have tried a couple of things: using a .class instead of #id results in the same problem. I tried using the php code inside the div instead of echoing it out. Results in the same problem, works with "letter" but not with "artistlista".

Is there something that I'm missing or overlooking?

Edit:

I took Alexanders advice and removed the  for 25 other elements and tried making artistlista as .class to no avail. However, I noticed something strange. If I change the name of id #letter in css file to for example #test and do the same with the div to  format is ignored and I cannot see the text unless it is highlighted. I do not have another row in the css with "letter" in it so the problem is not there. I have a feeling that this might be related to my original question. It seems like id/classes won't be created correctly?

Comment: Here are some screenshots since I don't have 10 rep to post it in the OP, but image 1 is how it currently looks, Image 2 is how it looks when I change the div id to "letter", and image 3 is how it is supposed to look. 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIOEd.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0zy6.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQiNK.png

Comment: Did you check what was the HTML sent to your browser ? (see source code )  ... looks like you might have many div with same id ....

Comment: Please take pity on your readers and stick to what's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID. Try to switch all IDs in the snippets you shared to classes and see if it works. Having multiple elements with the same ID results in unpredictable behaviour from the browser, so your styles may or may not be applied.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks alot for the answer. Now what I had before was a <div id='letter'> pretty much repeating 26 times for each letter. I removed it now and simply have one element with that id. Now here is something very strange that I realised after updating the files. If I change the #letter id name in the css to for example "test", and do the same thing for the div i.e <div id='test'> the format is ignored and the letter can only be seen when highlighted until I change back to the name "letter" I've done a ctrl+F search for all my webfiles and cannot find another row with "letter" in it.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what exactly's happening without the source code. As a rule of thumb: if you don't **absolutely need** an ID in the HTML, don't use one. IDs are the devil's playthings, especially for CSS and they're more trouble than they're worth.  Look through your source (php, css, html) and make sure you've replaced all the IDs with classes. If you're still seeing weird behaviour afterwards, reload your page, go into dev tools on your browser and start deleting CSS rules one by one until you see a change. This way you'll see what rule is doing what and what's giving you pain.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the problem. Like I suspected from the start it was something very simple. The code was correct, but I took Alexanders advice and decided to echo out the div for each letter instead of having it directly in the HTML which also gives a better structure. The problem itself was the website cache, since I run the website locally (I maybe should have mentioned it in the OP) the cache would override the new file and keep the old settings. Running it in incognito solved it and everything works as intended now.